# Why is the /etc/hosts file not working?

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns, hosts

I have been having problems with this for a while and have tried everything I know, so I figured it was finally time to ask for some help.

Any edit I make to `/etc/hosts` just doesn't work.

**Example:**

```
julian@ifrit:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ifrit
192.168.1.100   dev.julianfernand.es
```

In the example above, when I access **`dev.julianfernand.es`** (this doesn't exist), it should load from **`192.168.1.100`**.

If I ping, it works just fine. However when I access **`dev.julianfernand.es`** using Google Chrome or Firefox, it doesn't.

Now, after I restart a couple times, it works. But since I work at a managed WordPress hosting company, I deal with many situations where I have to edit my file to see the customer's website on our server.

I just can't keep restarting my computer. It isn't productive at all. Restarting the networking service doesn't work, same for clearing cache (even internal Chrome DNS cache).

Does anyone have an idea here? This happens with elementaryOS (based on Ubuntu 12.04) and Ubuntu 13.10 (daily). Haven't tried with any other version yet.

**PS:** if this matter, I have a NGINX server running on this machine with PHP-FPM and MySQL.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hard to know the problem. When accessing the site via hostname (dev.julianfernand.es) fails, can you access it via ip address (192.168.1.100) ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes, I can. However since our company doesn't uses the default "access IP to access website" idea from shared hosts, this doesn't work.

Comment: I was not suggesting you access websites via ip as a long term solution. The information helps debugging though as it excludes other problems from firewall to routing to server side issues.

Comment: What about if you type the ip address in the address bar of your browser ?

Answer (score 17):

In Ubuntu if you want to flush DNS cache, you need to restart `nscd` daemon.

Install `nscd` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nscd
```

Flush DNS Cache in Ubuntu Using the following command:

```
sudo service nscd restart
```

OR

```
sudo service dns-clean start
```

Reference: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/05/how-to-flush-clear-dns-cache-under.html

Comment: Please also check your Nginx configuration and error log file. There must be some clue in there when you access the site.

Comment: Since 15.04 with systemd: [`sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html)

Answer (score 8):

For me the solution was to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file (you may use command `sudo vim /etc/nsswitch.conf`). I've changed line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

to:

```
hosts:          dns files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

and now it is working as expected!

Comment: You probably want `files` as the first entry if you want `/etc/hosts` to take precedence over results from DNS servers.

Comment: That is strange but it is not a mistake, I have to have exactly this order to make it work.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had one server picking up the host name from my router rather than from /etc/hosts and couldn't figure out why. After seeing your suggestion, I checked all the servers and they all had the same /etc/nsswitch.conf except for the one giving me trouble. I updated that one to match the others (almost identical to your suggestion) and my problem went away.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me:
add

```
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts
```

in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/hosts.conf
```

kill dnsmasq and

```
service NetworkManager restart
```

Comment: makes no difference, the [Name Server switch](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-local-dns-using-etc-hosts-file-in-linux/) is the one that controls the order in which host name resolution is determined.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works in 12.04 through 13.04 by disabling `dnsmasq`, but it stopped working for me in 13.10. I found the following new solution for 13.10.

Edit your /etc/default/dnsmasq and change `ENABLED=1` to `ENABLED=0` and restart.

Comment: i do not have any dnsmasq file in specified path. I am on linux 15.04

Comment: There is no accepted answer anymore. Which answer are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

From: http://blog.calebthorne.com/2012/08/broken-etchosts-in-ubuntu-1204.html

A new "feature" in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition is to use `dnsmasq` as a plugin to NetworkManager for local DNS. Dnsmasq is intended to speed up DNS and DHCP services but comes with one unfortunate side effect: `dnsmasq` caches local DNS and ignores changes to `/etc/hosts`. I make frequent changes to the hosts file while working on websites so this "feature" was quite annoying.

The solution is to disable `dnsmasq` in the Networkmanager configuration file. Open `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment out the line:

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

My `NetworkManager.conf` file contains the following:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
# dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/993298

Comment: Tried this on 13.10 and elementaryOS, still nothing. But thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @JulianFernandes It appears this doesn't work on 13.10. I followed this advice and it worked back on 12.04, but after upgrading to 13.10, dnsmasq is back and I can't get rid of it.

Comment: OIC the problem - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/993298

Answer (score 2):

It's silly but the browser cache is the 'guilty' in my case = should be obvious for a developer :(

Another silly (obvious) thing what I missed, Browsers (Chrome, Mozilla) perform a google (or search engine) search directly from the address bar, so instead of resolving the address what you gave they search that word on the internet!

Solution:

- Once the /etc/hosts file is edited ping the chosen address! 
  If the ping command resolves the IP what you have given the 'hosts' file works!
- Clear your browser's cache (browsers cache DNS resolutions for some time (TTL))
- Disable the default search engine of the browser you are using

Comment: Yep - I think that's what we call a 'pro-tip'. haha - Always test `/etc/hosts` with `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple and Updated

1. Create `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/hosts.conf`.
2. Put lines like `address=/whatever/1.2.3.4` in it.
   See [the docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/dnsmasq.8.html)
   (look for `--address`).
   Wildcards are possible: `address/.whatever./1.2.3.4`.
3. Kill `dnsmasq` ([bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1483882)).
4. Restart it: `$ service network-manager restart`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, comment out below line by adding # in front of the line

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

and add

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Basically, configuration is reordered. Now domain lookup process will consult file first which is `/etc/hosts` and then it will consult DNS. With default configuration it consults DNS first before any other appropriate services or files.

For quick test whether its working or not you can use

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

to create a simple HTTP Server to serve files from directory and then comment below line in `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      01hw730983
```

and add

```
127.0.0.1       content
```

then go to a browser and type `content/`, if you able to see Directory structure its working else its not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your setup is a lot like mine.  I have a box running Ubuntu as my office server and development host.  On that box, I run Nginx, Apache, Tomcat, Rails apps and whatever else I need.

From my Mac, I can simply add a hosts entry and load the server with whatever name I need, but from a ElementaryOS client, that doesn't work.

I tried the fixes above, with no success.

What I did was to run Squid Proxy Server and add the hostnames to /etc/hosts on the server.  (Editing requires a restart of squid.)

After that, make the appropriate proxy settings in your browser or OS's control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on `/etc/hosts` file.

On my cloud service after cloning a server the permissions on hosts file changed from `644` to `600` so the file could not be read by apache (`www-data`) I guess.  I ran `sudo chmod 644 hosts` from `/etc` and that fixed it.

The problem started out as:

```
MongoConnectionException Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Previous connection attempts failed, server blacklisted.
```

I tracked it down to the server variable in MongoClient pointing at localhost. I was unable to ping localhost or the hostname.

Comment: I've sometimes had success changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in these sorts of cases

Answer (score 0):

These days (2021) Firefox is using DNS over HTTPS which you have to disable for it to respect your hosts file. I think this has some privacy implications, so get informed before you do it.

Go to Firefox settings, search DNS. Click `settings` next to `Configure how firefox connects to the internet`. At the bottom, uncheck `Enable DNS over HTTPS`