# /etc/hosts is ignored on 16.04 and no previous solution helps

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns, hosts

Entries in my /etc/hosts file are being ignored:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   google.com

$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.213.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par21s03-in-f142.1e100.net (216.58.213.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=10.3 ms
```

**I've been through ALL the solutions suggested in [the 12.04 thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347152/why-is-the-etc-hosts-file-not-working) but no dice.**

- Installing `nscd` just so I can restart it
- Editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` : it currently looks like:

  ```
  $ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
  # /etc/nsswitch.conf
  #

  passwd:         compat
  group:          compat
  shadow:         compat
  gshadow:        files

  hosts:          dns files
  networks:       files

  protocols:      db files
  services:       db files
  ethers:         db files
  rpc:            db files

  netgroup:       nis
  ```

  **Note: The `hosts` line was `files dns` before I started troubleshooting**, I changed it to `dns files` as per a suggestion from the 12.04 thread. Neither ordering produced any change in the behavior of my system, where /etc/hosts is concerned.
- Editing `/etc/default/dnsmasq` (No such file)
- Disabling `dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (no such file either)
- Creating a `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/hosts.conf` file and adding address resolution lines to it, killing dnsmasq (no such process) and doing `service network-manager restart` (no such service)
- Setting up a Squid proxy server (err, this won't work for my situation, and is a hack that's outside the scope of the question!)
- `sudo chmod 644 hosts` (permissions were already 644 beforehand)

I would have asked this as a comment in that thread, but I don't have enough reputation (50 needed).

By request, here's the output of `systemctl list-units '[Nn]etwork*' --all`:

```
$ systemctl list-units '[Nn]etwork*' --all
  UNIT                   LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB    DESCRIPTION
  networking.service     loaded    active   exited Raise network interfaces
● NetworkManager.service not-found inactive dead   NetworkManager.service
  network-online.target  loaded    active   active Network is Online
  network-pre.target     loaded    active   active Network (Pre)
  network.target         loaded    active   active Network
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the current content of your /etc/nsswitch.conf file and the output of `systemctl list-units '[Nn]etwork*' --all`

Comment: Edits done as you requested.

Comment: Have you tried with the default `nsswitch` order i.e. `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns` ? Note that `files` should come first.

Comment: I just tried that now, and it didn't change anything. Do I need to do anything to get the system to re-check the nsswitch.conf file? Also, as I noted in my previous edit above, the nsswitch.conf had been `files dns` BEFORE I started troubleshooting. Changing it to `dns files` was a troubleshooting suggestion from the other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all of the above, including [steeldriver's suggestion in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033557/etc-hosts-is-ignored-on-16-04-and-no-previous-solution-helps#comment1682011_1033557) I finally solved it...

...by rebooting the machine.

Now /etc/hosts works as it should.

I don't know WHICH solution did the trick, but applying all of them, and then rebooting... evidently did.

Answer (score 1):

`hosts:          dns files`

should be:

`hosts:          files dns`

This allows the system NS to query a file first. Namely, `/etc/hosts`.
The order in nsswitch.conf is important - also a reboot or network restart.